# How to get amount of data written to the SSD in its lifetime?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd

At home my Samsung SSD was shipped with a utility program that informs me about the the amount of data written to it through its lifetime. The Kingston SSD in my work notebook however lacks any software. Is there a third party solution to get this data or, the SSD doesn't even store this kind of information and Samsung's app only polls the write events of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Host writes is one of the SMART values on many SSDs.  CrystalDisk Info will let you read the SMART values.